# RBAC issue with Kubernetes Operator built with Kopf

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-operator

I'm trying to deploy a Kubernetes Operator using [Kopf](https://kopf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and I'm getting the following error:

```
kopf._cogs.clients.errors.APIForbiddenError: ('exchangerates.operators.brennerm.github.io is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:exchangerates-operator" cannot list resource "exchangerates" in API group "operators.brennerm.github.io" at the cluster scope', {'kind': 'Status', 'apiVersion': 'v1', 'metadata': {}, 'status': 'Failure', 'message': 'exchangerates.operators.brennerm.github.io is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:exchangerates-operator" cannot list resource "exchangerates" in API group "operators.brennerm.github.io" at the cluster scope', 'reason': 'Forbidden', 'details': {'group': 'operators.brennerm.github.io', 'kind': 'exchangerates'}, 'code': 403})
```

What's confusing is that if I check the permissions granted to the Service Account it looks like it has the correct permissions:

```
$ kubectl auth can-i list exchangerates --as=system:serviceaccount:default:exchangerates-operator
yes
$ kubectl auth can-i list exchangerates --as=system:serviceaccount:default:exchangerates-operator --all-namespaces
yes
```

Is there somewhere else I should be looking to troubleshoot the issue?

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud providor? It is important to reproduce your problem. Please provide info what exactly did you do inside your cluster

Comment: I'm using Minikube version 1.24.0 which pulled Kubernetes version 1.22.3. The ClusterRole is available on GitHub [here](https://github.com/brennerm/exchangerates-operator/blob/master/exchangerates-operator.yml).

Comment: As far as I remember, a star is not allowed in the verbs — it would give more privileges than intended when/if new verbs are added. The documentation has no examples with "*" (but they were there some day — I remember). Try listing all the verbs explicitly: Kopf needs `[list, watch, patch]`, your code may require some more.

Comment: I tried that prior and was getting the same error which is why I tried a wildcard. Regardless, why would the `auth can-i` command return `yes` if I'm getting an error.

Comment: Did you try in your `ClusterRoleBinding` set names in `"` characters? Try to put `name: "exchangerates-operator"` instead of `name: exchangerates-operator`.

Comment: You are right, "*" works. I tried your repo locally with Minikube 1.24.0 & K8s 1.22.3 — it works, there are no permission errors. The operator and the setup are both correct. Similarly for K3d — it works. I assume it is something with your local setup or old images left somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

User [Sergey Vasilyev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/857383/sergey-vasilyev) has tested this configuration and mentioned in the comment:

> You are right, "*" works. I tried your repo locally with Minikube 1.24.0 & K8s 1.22.3 — it works, there are no permission errors. The operator and the setup are both correct. Similarly for K3d — it works. I assume it is something with your local setup or old images left somewhere.

I also tested. I ran it locally on Minikube and had no problems. Your setup looks fine, everything works fine. Probably the problem may be with some dependencies in the image, or with Minikube leftovers. Bear in mind that Minikube is mainly used for testing and learning purposes so some of it's features might not be ideal. As for solving your problem, just try creating a new cluster.